# How to fill empty matrix row by row on Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, matrix

I need to create an empty matrix, fill it with lists, row by row. Each item in the list must be an item in the array.

```
list_1["1","2"]
list_2["3","4"]
add to:
matrix=[["0","0"] 
        ["0","0"]]
therefore:
matrix=[["1","2"] 
        ["3","4"]]
Note: 0 denote empty.
```

Comment: what is this for?

Comment: you can define the matrix as a list and append values into it, it this what you want to achieve? matrix = [] matrix.append(list1) matrix.append(list2)

Comment: `matrix[0] = list_1`, `matrix[1] = list_2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix object you're referring to doesn't exist in Python, you can create a list of lists and treat it as a matrix unless you need something more specific.

In your case you should have something like:

```
list_1 = ["1", "2"]
list_2 = ["3", "4"]
matrix = [list_1,
           list2]
print(matrix)
```

Returns this:

```
[["1", "2"], ["3", "4"]]
```

In case I'm missing something let me know

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill a previously existent matrix instead of creating a new one, just equal the row to the desired list:

```
matrix[0] = list_1
matrix[1] = list_2
```

And you can simply equal the matrix to a list of lists for faster results, which at the end is what a matrix represents.